# Set next week when clicks button

Tags: java, calendar

I want to set the CalendarVariabele Today on the first day of the next month when the user clicks on the arrow image.

I'm stuck with this, so does somebody may help me?

Code:

```
HTMLCode +="<img src='../images/pijl_rechts_icon.png' title='next month' onClick='"+ today.add(today.MONTH, 1)  +"'/>";
```

Comment: please put some more code. What is error or exception ?

Comment: Is it possible to do a calculation in a Onclick statement?
I just want to add 1 month to the variable Today

Answer (score 0):

`onClick='"+ today.add(today.MONTH, 1)  +"` is not possible. you can just print the string in console, or open the html in editor to see what actually it writes in htmlString. onClick, you can call a javascript function and from there you can change the date, but not via java. 
To explain this, your java code is in server side, once your browser shows the page, it is already generated client side codes in html and javascript.

 So while generation `+ today.add(today.MONTH, 1)  +` already changed to something else in html.